# WPF - how to focus an usercontrol from code behind

Tags: wpf, user-controls, focus

I have an user control with `Focusable=true` and `IsTabStop=true`.

I can focus it using Tab key. but I need to focus it from code.

I tried `uc.Focus()` and `Keyboard.Focus(uc)` but it doesn't work.

Comment: it could just be that some other control is stealing focus away from your `UserControl` the second it gets focus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tejas is probably correct. If WPF is doing some rendering/layout update, you want to postpone the .Focus() task a little and not get in WPF's way. Try this:

```
using System.Windows.Threading;

...

Action focusAction = () => uc.Focus();
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(focusAction, DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using [FocusManager.SetFocusedElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.focusmanager.setfocusedelement.aspx)

```
FocusManager.SetFocusedElement(parentElement, uc);
```